# Html Agility - need to give Div tag that has no attributes

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am trying to get a div that has no attribute class.

I'm tried a number of items but it can't seem to find anything under a specific div tag that has no attributes.

If a div tag has no attributes and just  is there a way to get it via html agility?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1lAb.jpg

**Update:**

It seems that if a  is just like this it isn't even pulling it into the HTML.

So the classes that I am looking for are not in the html at all.

So the only thing I can assume is that if the div tag is blank (no class, no attributes) that my download html code is not even pulling it in?